# Django form not submitting

Tags: python, django, forms

Recently, I've been working on a project to make certain tasks that are crucial to a project I am a part of become a lot easier.

The form was working the last time I checked it (a month ago). Since then, I moved it off of my computer and on to a server. The form is no longer submitting.

```
#forms.py

from django import forms
from .models import OnlineEssay, HardCopy, FaceToFaceConference

class OnlineEssayClientForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = OnlineEssay
        fields = [
            "client_first_name",
            "client_last_name",
            "client_grade",
            "client_teacher",
            "client_email",
            "feedback_primary",
            "feedback_secondary",
            "essay_file",
        ]
        labels = {
            'client_first_name': ('First Name'),
            'client_last_name': ('Last Name'),
            'client_grade': ('Grade Level (As Number)'),
            'client_teacher': ('Teacher'),
            'client_email': ('Email Address'),
            'feedback_primary': ('I need/would like feedback on:'),
            'feedback_secondary': ('And,'),
        }


class OnlineEssayTutorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = OnlineEssay
        fields = [
            "essay_type",
            "client_first_name",
            "client_last_name",
            "client_grade",
            "client_teacher",
            "client_email",
            "feedback_primary",
            "feedback_secondary",
            "essay_file",
            "essay_tutor",
            "essay_feedback",
        ]

class HardCopyTutorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = HardCopy
        fields = [
            "essay_type",
            "client_first_name",
            "client_last_name",
            "client_grade",
            "client_teacher",
            "feedback_primary",
            "feedback_secondary",
            "essay_tutor",
            "essay_feedback",
        ]

class FaceToFaceConferenceTutorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FaceToFaceConference
        fields = [
            "essay_type",
            "client_first_name",
            "client_last_name",
            "client_grade",
            "client_teacher",
            "feedback_primary",
            "feedback_secondary",
            "essay_tutor",
            "essay_feedback_notes",
        ]

    <!-- templates/submit.html -->
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
    {% load crispy_forms_tags %}
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      {% block head_title %}Welcome{% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
      {% block content %}
      <h1>Submit Your Essay</h1>
      <div class="bs-callout bs-callout-default">
        <p>Fill Out The Form Below, then press Submit</p>
      </div
     <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{%csrf_token%}
        {{form|crispy}}
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
      {% endblock %}
    </body>
    </html>


    #views.py
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django import http

    # Create your views here.
    from .forms import OnlineEssayClientForm
    def submit(request):
    form = OnlineEssayClientForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    context = {
        "form": form,
        "page_title" : "Submit Your Essay",
    }

    if form.is_valid():
       form.save()
       return http.HttpResponseRedirect('/success/')
    return render(request, "submit.html", context)
```

Comment: Can you share the views.py code?

Comment: Please paste your code directly into your question, not using pastebin.com. A traceback of what went wrong would be nice too.

Comment: If it was working before, check your computer's version of django and the server's version of django and make sure they match. You should also check the python versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was actually a pretty simple issue. I had forgot to close the `</div>` tag at the end of the callout. The form submits fine now.