# Django form not submitting - problem with form tag

Tags: html, django, django-forms

The signup page of my app is exhibiting unexpected behaviour. I'm using the standard django auth. After editing the html a bit, the form stopped submitting altogether. As in **nothing** would happen when I clicked submit. 
Similar behaviour to this [chap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780907/django-form-doesnt-work-on-click-submit), and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335459/django-form-not-being-submitted), and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32283836/django-form-not-submitting).

I've fixed it. For some reason, I needed to add an additional opening form tag. I have no idea why. This is what the html looks like now:

```
<form method="POST">  
        <form method="POST">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{ form.non_field_errors }}
          {% bootstrap_form form %}
          <input type="submit" class='btn btn-primary' value="Sign Up"/>


        </form>
```

Without the additional form tag at the top, it doesn't work. Can anyone explain what's going on here?

I also noticed that in Atom, when I only have the one opening tag, the editor highlights the tag in orange - meaning it's being treated as an attribute not a tag. When I have both opening tags, one still gets highlighted as an attribute.

Like I said, it's working now but I would prefer to rectify this if anyone in the community can help.

This is how the form renders in the browser:

```
    <div class="login-form">
            <h3 style="text-align: center;"><b>Create an Account</b></h3>

            <div class="container" <form="" method="POST">  
            <form method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="IX6HkTrNGNfH5CKgRtvp5II9vzg2fAUshMjlOe">

  <div class="form-group"><label class="control-label" for="id_username">Display Name</label><input type="text" name="username" maxlength="150" autofocus="" class="form-control" placeholder="Display Name" title="Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only." required="" id="id_username">

    <div class="help-block">Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.</div>

</div>
<div class="form-group"><label class="control-label" for="id_email">Email Address</label><input type="email" name="email" maxlength="254" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" title="" id="id_email"></div>
<div class="form-group"><label class="control-label" for="id_password1">Password</label><input type="password" name="password1" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" title="Your password can&amp;#39;t be too similar to your other personal information.Your password must contain at least 8 characters.Your password can&amp;#39;t be a commonly used password.Your password can&amp;#39;t be entirely numeric." required="" id="id_password1">

    <div class="help-block"><ul><li>Your password can't be too similar to your other personal information.</li><li>Your password must contain at least 8 characters.</li><li>Your password can't be a commonly used password.</li><li>Your password can't be entirely numeric.</li></ul></div>

</div>
<div class="form-group"><label class="control-label" for="id_password2">Password confirmation</label><input type="password" name="password2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password confirmation" title="Enter the same password as before, for verification." required="" id="id_password2">

    <div class="help-block">Enter the same password as before, for verification.</div>

</div>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Sign Up">


      </form>

            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could you include the HTML of how the form is rendered in your browser? Go to your page and right-click -> Show source. Then copy the whole `<form>` part.

Comment: Please show your generated HTML.... (after openning the page)

Comment: Done. Did it help at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an unclosed `div` tag immediately before the opening of the `form` tag.